# Making app to serve content from different base path (webpack and githubpages configurations)

Tags: angular, webpack, github-pages, html-webpack-plugin

I will try to clarify, questions title, because it wasn't easy to come up with title for my problem.

Question is more related with Webpack and githubpages configurations.

Background: I have made test project with angular2 on github(https://github.com/SomePeaceStudio/manatelpa). I was testing how to build project with webpack and then uglify it for production.

Problem: Locally when I build project and serve it, is served from localhost:8080/ and all the content is loaded correctly from localhost:8080/ ex:

```
GET localhost:8080/index.html
GET localhost:8080/app.js
GET localhost:8080/angular.png
```

and so on.. and it works like a magic.

When I push my 'dist' folder to gh-pages branch https://github.com/SomePeaceStudio/manatelpa/tree/gh-pages (I'm using gh-pages for project) so the path to my page would be:
https://somepeacestudio.github.io/manatelpa/
in this case it loads index.html from

```
GET https://somepeacestudio.github.io/manatelpa/
```

but it tries to get rest of my project from

```
GET https://somepeacestudio.github.io/app.bb10406340c613a712e4.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 46ms]
GET https://somepeacestudio.github.io/polyfills.bb10406340c613a712e4.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 44ms]
GET https://somepeacestudio.github.io/vendor.bb10406340c613a712e4.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 32ms]
GET https://somepeacestudio.github.io/app.bb10406340c613a712e4.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 67ms]
GET https://somepeacestudio.github.io/vendor.bb10406340c613a712e4.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 43ms]
GET https://somepeacestudio.github.io/app.bb10406340c613a712e4.js
```

and not from:

```
https://somepeacestudio.github.io/manatelpa/.....
```

no wonder it is not found and I do not know what to do about it, all webpack build configurations is in config/ folder (common + prod). I need to fix it.

I do not know how to deal with this problem.. I even do not know how to correctly title it to do some googling..

Should I change the way how content is loaded on my index.html page (it does it automatically) if so how to force it to load all my content from baseurl/manatelpa/.. . I search for some elegant solution, if there is one.

I'm by all means not a pro in webpack and ghpages configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple, I had to alter "publicPath" in webpack output object:

```
    publicPath: '/manatelpa/'
```

I edited it here:
https://github.com/SomePeaceStudio/manatelpa/blob/a60070da7a0507bc2b6e3ce15b9bfd71df756649/config/webpack.prod.js#L14

And now all my files are served from /manatelpa/...

Great!

Also, thanks to Rishat for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it doesn't have anything to do with Webpack configuration. What you really need is to change every `link` and `script` elements' `src` attribute value in such way that would refer to `/manatelpa` absolute path, and not just `/`.

So, basically, everything that looks like

```
<link href="/app.bb10406340c613a712e4.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

should look like

```
<link href="/manatelpa/app.bb10406340c613a712e4.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to make them all resolve correctly.

If the index.html is generated by Webpack, take a look at [`output.publicPath`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) Webpack setting.

Comment: Hey! It would be just great, that would solve my problem and I already thought about it. But the thing is, when I build all the links and script tags are added automatically by HtmlWebpackPlugin and you can see it here https://github.com/SomePeaceStudio/manatelpa/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L60 , I tried to find configuration possibilities for the baseUrl  - couldn't find any. And I will not do it manually.. any suggestions?